# Retrieve leaderboard position in Google play game services

Tags: android, google-play-games

Is there any way to retrieve the position of the current user in a leaderboard?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself but how about this ?

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardScore.html#getRank()

> public abstract long getRank ()
>
> Retrieves the rank returned from the server for this score. Note that
>   this may not be exact and that multiple scores can have identical
>   ranks. Lower ranks indicate a better score, with rank 1 being the best
>   score on the board.
>
> Returns Rank of score.

Comment: don't know how overlooked this. Thanks.

Comment: How do you get the LeaderboardScore? I cannot get one instance

Comment: Can some one update the answer with how to get this instance