# Getting the user Rank in Google Leaderboards (latest library)

Tags: android, google-play-services

I want to retrive the position of the current user in the Leaderboard.

I already implemented the Sign-in and the Leaderboard UI but I really can't get ride of this rank.

I tried to follow some old solution but couldn't implemented with the new version of the google library.

For example I tried that [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610936/how-to-get-rank-from-google-play-game-services-leaderboard), no luck.

Comment: Try checking `getRank()` as stated in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17830753/5995040). In the [LeaderboardScore](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardScore), you can use `getDisplayRank()`, `getDisplayRank()`, or ` getRank()`.

Comment: Still can't find an updated example to use it.

Answer (score -1):

Updating the player's score
    Game update their score on the leaderboard by calling `LeaderboardsClient.submitScore()`, and passing in the leaderboard ID and the raw score value.

The following code snippet as an example shows how your app can update the player’s score:

```
Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
    .submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_id), 1337);
```

A good practice is to define the leaderboard ID in your strings.xml file, so your game can reference the leaderboards by resource ID. When making calls to update and load player scores, make sure to also follow these best practices for to avoid exceeding your API quota.

Displaying a leaderboard
    To display leaderboard, call `LeaderboardsClient.getLeaderboardIntent()` to get an Intent to create the default leaderboard user interface. Your game can then bring up the UI by calling `startActivityForResult`.

The following code snippet as an example shows how your app can update the player’s score. In the code snippet, `RC_LEADERBOARD_UI` is an arbitrary integer for the request code.

```
private static final int RC_LEADERBOARD_UI = 9004;

private void showLeaderboard() {
  Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
      .getLeaderboardIntent(getString(R.string.leaderboard_id))
      .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
          startActivityForResult(intent, RC_LEADERBOARD_UI);
        }
      });
}
Notice that even though no result is returned, you have to use startActivityForResult so that the API can obtain the identity of the calling package.
```

after implementation -

To retrieve player stats data for the currently signed-in player, follow these steps:

Call the PlayerStatsClient.loadPlayerStats() method.
If the call is successful, Google Play games services returns a Task object which asynchronously loads a PlayerStats object. Use the methods of this object to retrieve data about the signed-in player’s activities in your app.

Example : 
public void checkPlayerStats() {
  Games.getPlayerStatsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
      .loadPlayerStats(true)
      .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task> task) {
          if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            // Check for cached data.
            if (task.getResult().isStale()) {
              Log.d(TAG, "using cached data");
            }
            PlayerStats stats = task.getResult().get();
            if (stats != null) {
              Log.d(TAG, "Player stats loaded");
              if (stats.getDaysSinceLastPlayed() > 7) {
                Log.d(TAG, "It's been longer than a week");
              }
              if (stats.getNumberOfSessions() > 1000) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Veteran player");
              }
              if (stats.getChurnProbability() == 1) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Player is at high risk of churn");
              }
            }
          } else {
            int status = CommonStatusCodes.DEVELOPER_ERROR;
            if (task.getException() instanceof ApiException) {
              status = ((ApiException) task.getException()).getStatusCode();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to fetch Stats Data status: "
                + status + ": " + task.getException());
          }
        }
      });
}

Comment: Your code explaining how to implement the Leaderboard, I'm asking How to retrieve the Rank of the user.

Comment: Still don't think is the right answer, I want a different thing